# Making a Hello World Spring Web Flow... what am I missing

Tags: spring-webflow

I am making a Hello World Spring Web Flow... what am I missing... I could not find any good examples so I started to make one.  can someone please tell me what I am missing to make my Hello World Flow work.

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>MyFlow</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

spring-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">


    <context:component-scan base-package="org.uftwf.controller" />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />

        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

helloworld-flow.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE flow PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD WEBFLOW 1.0//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-webflow-1.0.dtd">

<flow start-state="helloworld">
    <view-state id="helloworld" view="helloworld">
    </view-state>
</flow>
```

index.jsp

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Spring 3.0 MVC Series</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="hello.html">Say Hello (Spring MVC)</a><p>
    <a href="hello.html">Say Hello (Spring-Web-Flow)</a>
</body>
</html>
```

So what do I have to change to get my flow working

Comment: You are missing the configuration that wires springMVC to Spring WebFlow. I mean, when the springMVC dispatcher gets request, it should have something to send that request to your flow.. those config items are - flowExecutor and flowRegistry etc. Follow this example [link]http://www.ervacon.com/products/swf/intro/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the flow resolver on the springmvc-servlet.xml

```
<!-- define controller mappings for webflow -->
<bean id="webflowHandlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="order" value="5"/>
    <property name="mappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="**/hello">flowController</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- webflow configuration -->
<import resource="spring-webflow.xml"/>
```

And in your flow file use:

```
<!-- setup webflow -->
<bean id="mvcViewFactoryCreator" class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.builder.MvcViewFactoryCreator">
<property name="viewResolvers" ref="tilesViewResolver"/>
</bean>

<flow:flow-builder-services id="flowBuilderServices" view-factory-creator="mvcViewFactoryCreator"/>

<flow:flow-registry id="flowRegistry" base-path="/WEB-INF/flows" flow-builder-services="flowBuilderServices">
    <flow:flow-location-pattern value="/**/*-flow.xml"/>
</flow:flow-registry>

<flow:flow-executor id="flowExecutor" flow-registry="flowRegistry"/>
```

There may be more, but follow the link that @rrkwells suggested for a more complete example.